# Form is being Submitted every time The button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, forms

I am having a form in which I am saving 2 files and a field. The problem I am facing is every time I click the submit button the form is getting submitted. Although The text field is resetting, the file still consists the value of previous record. How to reset the file here once the form is submitted.

HTML

```
<form id="formOrder" autocomplete="off" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div class="row row-sm">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="row row-sm">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="input-group mb-4">
                        <input aria-label="Invoice ID" id="invoiceId" name="invoiceId" class="form-control" placeholder="Invoice ID" type="text">
                        <span class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group file-browser">
                        <input id="imageLabel" type="text" class="form-control browse-file" placeholder="Select Order Image" readonly>
                        <label class="input-group-btn">
                            <span class="btn btn-default">
                                Browse <input type="file" name="image[]" id="orderImage" style="display: none;" multiple>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="orderImagePreview">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-0 mt-3 justify-content-end">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="_add" name="_add" class="btn btn-primary btn-size" value="Add"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
// BUTTON CLICK SUBMISSION
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#_add").click(function(){        
        $("#formOrder").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../order/add.php',
                data: new FormData(this),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                async: false,
                autoUpload: false,
                success: function(response){
                    $('.statusMsg').html('');
                    if(response.status == 1){
                        $('#formOrder')[0].reset(); //FORM TO RESET AFTER SUBMISSION
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<p class="alert alert-success">'+response.message+'</p>');
                        alert('received');
                        $('.orderImagePreview').empty();
                        document.getElementById('#orderImage').value= null; //TO MAKE THE IMAGE LABEL EMPTY
                    }else{
                        $('.statusMsg').html(alert(response.message));
                    }
                    $('#formOrder').css("opacity","");
                    $(".submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    });
});

// Multiple images preview in browser
$(function() {
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;
            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }
    };

    $('#orderImage').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.orderImagePreview');
        $( 'div.orderImagePreview' ).empty();
    });
});

$('#orderImage').on("change", function(){
    var input = document.getElementById ("imageLabel");
    var imageCount = $(this)[0].files.length;
    if(imageCount > 0){
        input.placeholder = imageCount+" Image Attached";
    }else{
        input.placeholder = "Select Order Image";
    }
});
```

Where I am making the mistake? The debugging should be to reset the form with file or the method of form submission? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: <input id="_add" name="_add" class="btn btn-primary btn-size" value="Add"/>
Can you remove type= "submit" and check again?

Comment: @Mangesh — So it becomes a text field?

Comment: yup and use button HTML element.
or else you can add
$("#_add").click(function(event){event.preventDefault()}
for input click too.
Same you have added for form submit

Comment: @Mangeshso type becomes button?

Comment: <button  id="_add" name="_add" class="btn btn-primary btn-size">Add</button>

Comment: @Mangesh — That will still submit the form.

Comment: This will not submit the form on button click.
you want to prevent that too.
Wait I will provide an example

Comment: @Mangesh `<button>` *without* `type=` will default to `type=submit` - you *must* add `type='button'` if you don't want the button to submit the form.

Comment: Tip: use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using the FileReader

Comment: @Endless Thanks for the tip. Will check on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $("#_add").click(function(){        
>     $("#formOrder").on('submit', function(e){
> ```

Just create a submit handler when the document loads.

Don't add it when the button is clicked.

Comment: The comment is the same as the example provided. you want me to remove button click function?

Comment: @RoshanZaid — The material quoted from your code is your code to show you where the problem is. It isn't edited at all. Yes, remove the first line of that and the matching end of the function.

Comment: yes, you are the best. now every time I click it takes empty value to which I should error handle. Thanks.